# Which algorithm for finding best two options for network connectivity for 1200 sites?

Tags: algorithm, analytics

I'm a data engineer who is trying to solve an interesting analytics problem. I have linked to a small Excel workbook with sample data.

Problem statement:

A company has branches in 1200 locations. They want network connectivity to all the branches. They demand two connectivity solutions from two separate service providers to ensure service continuity.

There are 20+ service providers, each having up to 30 connectivity product offerings. Not all service providers are present in all locations and some locations are covered by only some of a supplier's products. Product types are ranked from best to worst.

Higher capacity is better, but overall budget is a constraint.

Coming up with the right suppliers and products per location is a tedious process, especially when other constraints are included.

Searching suggests that LTR might the class of algorithm to use, but please point me to any better solution or approach.

[Link to Workbook on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/laohtrotmr96fh5/Connectivity.xlsx?dl=0)

Thanks,
Alan.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTR - Can you expand that acronym?

Comment: what is your desired outcome? A choice of two products from two different providers for each location which falls within cost constraints and otherwise provides maximal capacity? Do you want to minimize the total number of different providers and products, or maximize it? What other constraints are you considering?

Comment: tucuxi, LTR in this context is "Learning to Rank". And your questions are on point. The desired outcome would combine the rank of Product Type (e.g. Fiber) and highest capacity. For simplicity, let's state that two different suppliers must be chosen per site and only one of their products. For example, Metropolis would have Hydra supplying product H-24-10 and Spectre supplying product S-5-24 if there was no budget constraint. For a later version, I'd like to add extra constraints such as excluding a supplier or a product type for a specific site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems like a natural fit for integer programming. You can describe the variables, constraints, and objective function to a library like PuLP and let a library do the dirty work of finding an optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll check that out too.

Comment: @Ruan Guys, I've checked all your solutions.  I'm open to be corrected in this statement, so please do so if I've misunderstood. I think all the solutions provide only the best case. If you recall, the problem statement requires the top 2 solutions per site, with different suppliers. All within a budget constraint. Will any of the approaches you provided address that?

Comment: @AlanCollins Yes, you can either encode a diversity constraint into the IP itself or just ask the solver for multiple solutions in descending order of quality.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll dive in.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is small, and you can brute-force it as long as the cost function is not too complex.

You have 1200 locations, each with 20 providers with 30 offerings each. You want to choose 2 offerings per location, from independent providers: (20*30 + 19*30) + 1200 = 1.4M solutions to analyze.

You can run simple backtracking to find the solution that minimizes the total cost, and since the problem is not too large, it should only take a few seconds to run. The basic pseudo-code could be:

```
 bruteForce(partialAnswer, currentLocation, constraints, bestAnswer):
     for (each possible pairOfOfferings from different provicers at
               currentLocation):
         add pairOffering to partialAnswer
         if (pairOfOffering ok according to constraints):
             if (currentLocation is last location left):
                if (partialAnswer beats bestAnswer according to cost function):
                    update bestAnswer
             othwerwise:
                call bruteForce(
                         partialAnswer, nextLocation, constraints, bestAnswer)
         remove pairOffering from partialAnswer
```

Pruning the search space can speed this up significantly, but unless you have an order of magnitude more locations, or you really need sub-second response times, it is probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks tucuxi. I'm going to turn that into Python code. However, the selfish reason I want to do it with analytics is to expand my knowledge. This data set brought an interesting dimension, one I had not yet covered with the ML I'd tackled so far. Thanks for your thoughts and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the [minimum-cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) , for which the [network simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_simplex_algorithm) is very hard to beat on a small scale.

[MCFSimplex](https://github.com/frangio68/Min-Cost-Flow-Class) is [probably the fastest](http://blog.sommer-forst.de/tag/mcfsimplex/) open source network simplex implementation available, so that may be what you're looking for. And it has [a Python wrapper](https://github.com/sommergis/pymcfsimplex).

Comment: Thanks Ruan. I'll check that out.